# Partition an n-dimensional "square" space into cubes

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization

right now I am stuck solving the following "semi"-mathematical Problem.

I would like to partition an n-dimensinal restricted space (a hypercube to be precise)

`D={(x_1, ...,x_n), x_i \in IR and -limits<=x_i<=limits \forall i<=n}`  Into smaller cubes.

Meaning I would like to specify `n,limits,m` where `m` would be the number of partitions per side of the cube - `2*limits/m` would be the length of the small cubes and I would get `m^n` such cubes.

Now I would like to return a vector of vectors containing some distinct coordinates of these small cubes. (or perhaps one could represent the cubes as objects which are characterized by a vector pointing to the "left" outer corner ? )

Basically I have no idea whether something like that is even doable using C++. Implementing this for fixed n does not pose a problem. But I would like to enable the user to have free choice of the dimension.

**Background:** Something like that would be priceless in optimization. Where one would partition the space into smaller ones and use e.g. a genetic algorithms on each of the subspaces and later compare the results. Thus huge initial Populations could be avoided and the search results drastically improved. 
Also I am just curious whether sth. like that is doable :)

**My Suggestion:**  Use B+ Trees ?

Comment: It sounds to me that you're looking for an n-dimensional extension of octrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

Comment: Does sth. like that exist ?

Comment: I'm sure it does, but I don't know what it would be called. It should be relatively straightforward to extend the octree to N dimensions. Instead of 8 children per node, you will need n^2. The insert, find and remove operations are basically very similar, too.

Comment: Discretizing the space like this is definitely not priceless in optimization; in fact it causes the set of variables to blow up exponentially. I think much of optimization is devoted to techniques for avoiding this.

Comment: certainly - but in case when you need to put a grid on your n-dminsional space - it would be pretty useful. I agree with you that this is not the most efficient way - but in some cases it might be the most accurate. So when precission is more valuable than runtime. But still your argument is competely valid :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let m be the number of partitions per dimension, i.e. per *edge*, of the hypercube D.

Then there are m^n different subspaces S of D, like you say.  Let the subspaces S be uniquely represented by integer coordinates S=[y_1,y_2,...,y_n] where the y_i are integers in the range 1, ..., m.  In Cartesian coordinates, then, S=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) where Delta*(y_i-1)-limits <= x_i < Delta*y_i-limits, and Delta=2*limits/m.

The "left outer corner" or origin of S you were looking for is just the point corresponding to the smallest x_i, i.e. the point (Delta*(y_1-1)-limits, ..., Delta*(y_n-1)-limits). Instead of representing the different S by this point, it makes a lot more sense (and will be faster in a computer) to represent them using the integer coordinates above.